# Proof: $f$ is continuous at $p$ iff for all $x_n\to p$, $f(x_n)\to f(p)$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

> Let $M, N$ be metric spaces, $f:M\to N$, and $p\in M$.
>
> $f$ is continuous at $p$ $\iff$ for all ${x_n}\in M$ s.t $x_n\to p$, $f(x_n)\to f(p)$

$\Leftarrow:$ Proof by contradiction: Let assume the that  for all ${x_n}\in M$ s.t $x_n\to p$, $f(x_n)\to f(p)$ but $f$ is not continuous at $p$.

$f$ is not continuous at $p$ therefore there is $\varepsilon >0$ s.t for all $\delta > 0$ we have $d(x_n,p)<\delta$ but $d(f(x_n),f(p))> \varepsilon$.
This is true for all $\delta$ so does for $\delta = \frac{1}{n}$ so $d(x_n,p)<\frac{1}{n}$ but $d(f(x_n),f(p))> \varepsilon$.

So it is true that $x_n \to p$ as $d(x_n,p)<\frac{1}{n}$ but $f(x_n) \not\to f(p)$ as $d(f(x_n),f(p))> \varepsilon$ which is a contradiction.

$\Rightarrow:$ Let assume $f$ is continuous at $p$ and $x_n\to p$ therefore let there be $\varepsilon$ there is $\delta > 0$ s.t $f(B(p,\delta))\subseteq B(f(p),\varepsilon)$
On the other hand, $x_n\to p$ let there be $\varepsilon > 0$ there is $N$ s.t for all $N\leq n$: $d(x_n,p) < \varepsilon$ or $x_n\in B(p,\varepsilon)$ but  $f(B(p,\delta))\subseteq B(f(p),\varepsilon)$ so $f(x_n)\in  f(B(p,\delta))\subseteq B(f(p),\varepsilon)$ or  $f(x_n)\in   B(f(p),\varepsilon)$ and therefore $f(x_n)\to f(p)$

There are few points that I am not sure about:

1. why we needed to use $\delta = \frac{1}{n}$, we assume that $x_n\to p$ so we can say that $d(x_n,p)\to 0$
2. Why could we conclude that  $f(x_n)\in f(B(p,\delta)$?

Comment: In the $\impliedby$ part, you never define $x_n$. (I think I know what you probably mean to do but as written, it does not make much sense.)

Answer (score 1):

For 2, since the property: "for every $\epsilon >0 $ it exists an $N$ s.t. $\forall n \geq N$ $d(x_n,p) < \epsilon$" is true for every $\epsilon$, you can just choose $\epsilon \leq \delta$ to obtain that definetely $x_n \in B(p,\delta)$.